# Theme the taxonomy tags list in the node teaser

Tags: 7, theming, taxonomy-terms

In my Drupal site I have node teasers that show taxonomy terms. As it stands they are like:

Tags:

Houses

```
<div class="field field-name-field-tags field-type-taxonomy-term-reference field-label-above">
  <div class="field-label">Tags:</div>
    <div class="field-items"><div rel="schema:category" class="field-item even">
        <a datatype="" property="rdfs:label skos:prefLabel" typeof="skos:Concept" href="/tags/houses">Houses</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I cant locate where the `<a>` anchor tag is being generated. I want to be able to change it to a `<button>` tag instead of anchor.

Any ideas how to do this?

Comment: Have you tried hook_field_formatter_view()?

Comment: Hi mate, I have not tired `hook_field_formatter_view()` how would I implement this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at [this tutorial](http://www.metaltoad.com/blog/drupal-7-tutorial-creating-custom-formatters) that shows you how to create a custom formatter for specific field types. The taxonomy term field type machine name is `taxonomy_term_reference`

Comment: Brilliant tutorial, is there a way without creating a custom module?

Comment: If you intend to use the hooks in the tutorial, you need to create a module . Creating a module for Drupal 7 is really simple - there are many tutorials online. Other than that, I guess you could try using jQuery to replace the tag <button> for <a>, but I don't know enough jQuery to guide you. You would need to modify your theme .info file to load the .js file that contains the jQuery functions. I find this more complex than creating a module

Comment: Would it have to be a similar method if I wasn't changing the anchor to button but wanted to add extra classes to the anchor tag?

Comment: Check out field_formatter_class https://www.drupal.org/project/field_formatter_class. It allows you do ad css classes to the <div> wrapper around the <a> tag